# If A is an open set and if B is a closed set, then A + B is an open set

Tags: general-topology

> If $A$ is an open set and if $B$ is a closed set, then $A + B$ is an open
>   set.

We know $(A+B)^o \subset A+B$. We need to prove $A+B \subset (A+B)^o$. We need to prove $x$ is an interior point of $A+B$. Let $x\in A+B$, $x=a+b, a\in A $ ,$b\in B$. $ a$ is the interior point of $A$. $\implies$ $\exists$ open set containing $a$ in $A$. $b\in B \implies$ Every neighbourhood of $b$ have a non-empty intersection with $B$.

Using this fact, how to construct a neighbourhood of $x$ which sits in $A+B$? Please help me. Is there any quick alternative way to check the openness?

Comment: This is true for any set $B$. I presume you are working in $\Bbb R^n$ but you could use any Abelian topological group. In general $A+b$ is an open set contained in $A+B$ with $a+b$ as an element.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown not in $\mathbb R^n$. general case.

Comment: Can you help me, how to find the neighbourhood of $x$? using the given information?

Comment: Maybe you mean that  we are on topological vector space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide to an alternative approach:

- If $A$ is open, show that $A+b$ is open.
- Show that $\bigcup_{b \in B} (A+b)$ is open.

Edit:

To construct your desired neighborhood, prove the following:

If $x=a+b$ where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$, since $A$ is open, there exists an open set $O$ containing $a$ in $A$. We claim that $O+b$ is an open set containing $x$ in $A+B$.

Comment: Thank you. the answer is wonderful.

Answer (score 2):

In topological groups setting? Then for any open set $A$ and any set $B$, $A+B=\displaystyle\bigcup_{x\in B}(x+A)$. That $x+A$ is open by the homeomorphism $\cdot\rightarrow x+\cdot$

So $A+B$ is open.